# How to avoid the FOR loop in this diff calculation grouped by a column and also avoid the SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In this dataframe I was wondering if there was a better and vectorized way to do the diff operation between rows grouped by 'ID', rather than doing the FOR loop through unique 'ID'.

In addition, if there is a better way to avoid having this warning message, even when slicing with .loc as said:
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'TimeStamp' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
    'Id': [99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 98, 99, 99],
    'Col1': [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 12, 12], 
    'Col2': [3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1],
    'Col3': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Time': [110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 160, 170, 180, 190], 
    'Check': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.sort_values(by='TimeStamp', ascending=True, inplace=True) 
print(df)

Output:
|   TimeStamp |   Id |   Col1 |   Col2   |   Col3 |   Time |   Check |
|------------:|-----:|-------:|---------:|-------:|-------:|--------:|
|           1 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      1 |    110 |       0 |
|           2 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      2 |    120 |       0 |
|           3 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      3 |    130 |       0 |
|           4 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      1 |    140 |       0 |
|           5 |   99 |     10 |        1 |      2 |    150 |       0 |
|           6 |   99 |     12 |        3 |      1 |    160 |       0 |
|           7 |   98 |     14 |        1 |      1 |    170 |       0 |
|           8 |   99 |     12 |        3 |      1 |    180 |       0 |
|           9 |   99 |     12 |        1 |      1 |    190 |       0 |
```

```
df_l,df_m = pd.DataFrame(),pd.DataFrame()
for i in df['Id'].unique():
  df_l = df.loc[df['Id']==i,:]
  df_l.loc[:,'TimeDiff'] = df_l['Time'].diff() #ERROR: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice  
                                               #from a DataFrame. Try using 
                                               #.loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
  df_m=pd.concat([df_l,df_m], ignore_index=True)    #append df
df_m.loc[:,'TimeDiff'] =df_m['TimeDiff'].fillna(0.0)
df_m.sort_values(by='TimeStamp', ascending=True, inplace=True)
print(df_m.to_markdown(index=False),'\n')

Output:
|   TimeStamp |   Id |   Col1 |   Col2   |   Col3 |   Time |   Check |   TimeDiff |
|------------:|-----:|-------:|---------:|-------:|-------:|--------:|-----------:|
|           1 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      1 |    110 |       0 |          0 |
|           2 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      2 |    120 |       0 |         10 |
|           3 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      3 |    130 |       0 |         10 |
|           4 |   99 |     10 |        3 |      1 |    140 |       0 |         10 |
|           5 |   99 |     10 |        1 |      2 |    150 |       0 |         10 |
|           6 |   99 |     12 |        3 |      1 |    160 |       0 |         10 |
|           7 |   98 |     14 |        1 |      1 |    170 |       0 |          0 |
|           8 |   99 |     12 |        3 |      1 |    180 |       0 |         20 |
|           9 |   99 |     12 |        1 |      1 |    190 |       0 |         10 |
```

Thanks!

I ended up doing the FOR loop through the grouped dataframe's column.
But I was wondering if there was a better and vectorised way to calculate the diff.
Also I would like to avoid having the SettingWithCopyWarning if there is a better way to carry out this operations.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.diff.html)/[`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) :

```
df["TimeDiff"] = df.groupby("Id")["Time"].diff().fillna(0, downcast="infer")
```

​
Output :

```
print(df)

   TimeStamp  Id  Col1  Col2  Col3  Time  Check  TimeDiff
0          1  99    10     3     1   110      0         0
1          2  99    10     3     2   120      0        10
2          3  99    10     3     3   130      0        10
3          4  99    10     3     1   140      0        10
4          5  99    10     1     2   150      0        10
5          6  99    12     3     1   160      0        10
6          7  98    14     1     1   170      0         0
7          8  99    12     3     1   180      0        20
8          9  99    12     1     1   190      0        10
```

Comment: Thanks, it works nicely!
How can we do the same concept instead of three nested FOR loop:

``    for i in df['ID'].unique():                   #loop same ID
``      df_i = df.loc[df['ID']==i,:]                #df slice per ID
``      for j in df_i['Col1'].unique():             #loop same Col1
``        df_j = df_i.loc[df_i['Col1']==j,:]        #df slice per Col1
``        df_j.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) #reset index
``        for k, row in df_j.iterrows():    #loop each row 
``   ...